# Connect one PC to separated networks with the same subnet mask

Tags: windows, networking, routing, subnet

I need to connect one PC with two network interfaces, Windows 10, to two separated LANs, that share the same subnet mask (and same IP addresses):[image]

The purpose is have a bidirectional connection (TCP, UDP) between My PC and the all others PCs, not between PCs in different LANs.
Each LAN has a switch (no routers or firewalls). Unfortunately I cannot change the IP addresses of these networks, but I have full rights on My PC set up and its network interfaces.
Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: You could use a VM and give it one NIC, while the host uses the other NIC. If this is a possible solution, let me know your preferred virtual machine product.

Comment: Hi @harrymc, unfortunately it's not a possible solution, I have a software (one instance only) that must communicate with all the PCs

Comment: That's not possible, as you have no way to know at the network level which version of `192.168.100.2` for example you're trying to connect to, and therefore which NIC to route the request through. Even manually adding routes wouldn't work, as that could only allow you to connect to one of those two machines, while the other would become inaccessible. Only real option would be to let the app do any management on one LAN at a time, so only one is connected at any time.

Comment: Actually, it might be possible with something like a hardware firewall that supports configuring 1 to 1 NAT, so you connect that between NIC2  and LAN B, with your side of it being on 192.169.200.0/24 and it having 1 to 1 translations between the existing .100.x addresses, and correspending .200.x addresses. Then YOUR computer could address both networks via .100.x and .200x, but the networks themselves would remain the same... which kit would allow that and whether it's even possible or practical on the other hand is another matter.

Comment: Hi @KeithLangmead, thank you for your comment, I'll investigate on some 1-1 NAT hardware device

Answer (score 0):

> I need to connect one PC with two network interfaces, Windows 10, to two separated LANs, that share the same subnet mask (and same IP addresses)

That's not possible, generally. Your PC has no way to properly choose the currently desired interface to the intended destination = route based on destination IP address.

Your problem *could* be solved using an elaborate translation scheme using at least one NAT router, but I'll leave that to someone else to answer. The better choice is to renumber one of the subnets.